# Multiple HashMaps for cache storage, or one HashMap?

Tags: java

I have a question regarding best practices & RAM usage in Java.

If I have the object:

```
public class UserObject {

    private final UUID uuid;
    private final double wallet;

    public UserObject(UUID uuid, double wallet) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.wallet = wallet;
    }

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public double getWallet() {
        return wallet;
    }
}
```

And I want to get a specific UserObject reference both from their UUID and Wallet. Which would be considered best practice?

Alternative 1:

```
public class UserManager {

    private final Map<UUID, UserObject> userUUIDMap = new HashMap<>();

    public UserObject getUserByUUID(UUID uuid) {
        return userUUIDMap.get(uuid);
    }

    public UserObject getUserByWallet(double wallet) {
        for(UserObject user : userUUIDMap.values()) {
            if(user.getWallet() == wallet)
                return user;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Alternative 2 (In this case, the wallet would also be unique per User):

```
public class UserManager {

    private final Map<UUID, UserObject> userUUIDMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<Double, UserObject> userByWallet = new HashMap<>();

    public UserObject getUserByUUID(UUID uuid) {
        return userUUIDMap.get(uuid);
    }

    public UserObject getUserByWallet(double wallet) {
        return userByWallet.get(wallet);
    }
}
```

In alternative 2, I would achieve O(1) in both methods, however I would also need to remember to update both maps when adding/removing elements. Also, would it require more RAM using alternative 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I this case, if you need to be able to retrieve your objects both by UUID and Wallet, than the Alternative 2 would be the correct one. True, you use more memory, but the entire idea of cache is a FAST access. So the first alternative doesn't give it to you when you need to retrieve your objects by wallet. In case that you need to save on memory, there are algorithms to shorten your caches. For instance, keep in cache only values that are used often. Or evict from cache values that haven't been requested longer then some timeout and so forth.